# Request Class Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, request, laravel-5

i use this code for return articles but not run this code and return blank,
how to solve this problem?

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\taxonomy;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class newPostController extends Controller {

public function submitArticle(Request $request){
    $name = $request->all();
    return $name;
}
```

first time:
[image]

for next record: 
[image]

Comment: I don't know why are you ignoring my post, cause it was first and correct, all other answers are just copy of the same clause. But anyway, I've answered your second question about getting empty result for the seconds time. Please check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function submitArticle(Request $request){
    $name = $request->all();
    return $name;
}
```

**Update**

You're getting empty result seconds time, because first time you're sending info through request, so `$request` has some data. If you reload the page, you do not send any info, that's why it's empty. It's just how it works.

Usually, when you're using `$request` data, you want to store it in DB or somehting and then redirect somewhere, for example, `return $redirect->back();` instead of your return clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public function submitArticle(Request $request){
    $name = $request->all();
    return $name;
}
```

add this line in your class

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Comment: This code runs only once but a second time, again, a blank page is displayed

Comment: Not sure what happening in second time, is it possible for you to share more details what are you doing with the request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the Request into your method:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\taxonomy;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class newPostController extends Controller {

public function submitArticle(Request $request){
    $name = $request->input();
    return $name;
}
```

Comment: not work `Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::all() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

Comment: @MeysamSaberi Are you submitting anything? Request is used for incoming request data. are you trying to get data from the database and display that?

Comment: I just want information to be displayed form submissions for JSON @angad-dubey